# Generate/use etags for compressed (.el.gz) libraries?

Tags: compression

I wanted to generate a tags table for the lisp libraries that my Emacs came with, located in

```
/path/to/emacs/25.1/lisp/
```

There's a mix of compressed and uncompressed files in that directory, so I ran `etags *.el{.gz,}` to build the TAGS file.

Now `find-tag` works, but `xref-find-definitions` only works for the uncompressed libraries.

For example, if I run `xref-find-definitions` with `copy-to-buffer`, which lives in `simple.el.gz`, it reports:

```
user-error: Rerun etags: ‘^(defun copy-to-buffer ’ not found in /path/to/emacs/25.1/lisp/simple.el
```

and inspecting the buffer-list shows a newly-created empty buffer named `simple.el`.

If I have `simple.el.gz` open before running the above command, it works correctly.

Looking in the TAGS file itself, I see that all the filenames end in `.el`, even those whose files on disk end in `.el.gz`, and I assume this related.

How can I properly build/use tags for these compressed files? Also, if I delete the TAGS file I generated, `xref-find-definitions` just works, whereas `find-tag` prompts me for a tags table to visit, so I'm curious how xref is finding references: is it using a TAGS file located elsewhere, or some other mechanism?

Comment: Please `M-x report-emacs-bug` with the exact steps to reproduce the problem (where you got Emacs from, which buffers you open and run the commands in, and so on).

Comment: @Dmitry I was assuming it was something I'm doing wrong, rather than a bug. I'll try to dig into the xref source code a bit before I report a bug.

Comment: A long time time later. Any joy here? I want xref-find-definitions to find stuff in /usr/share/emacs/*.el.gz but not joy despite creating a tags file and adding it to tags-table-list.

Comment: @RichieHH Sorry, I don't remember if I got any further with this. I eventually switched to using gtags: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnuGlobal

Answer (score 1):

File "etags.el.gz" has the following:

```
(cl-defmethod xref-location-marker ((l xref-etags-location))
  (with-slots (tag-info file) l
    (let ((buffer (find-file-noselect file)))
      (with-current-buffer buffer
        (save-excursion
          (etags-goto-tag-location tag-info)
          (point-marker))))))
```

If I use instead:

```
(cl-defmethod xref-location-marker ((l xref-etags-location))
  (with-slots (tag-info file) l
    (let (buffer)
      (if (file-exists-p file)
      (setq buffer (find-file-noselect file))
    (setq file (concat file ".gz"))
    (if (file-exists-p file)
        (setq buffer (find-file-noselect file))
      (user-error "file %s does not exist" file)))
      (with-current-buffer buffer
        (save-excursion
          (etags-goto-tag-location tag-info)
          (point-marker))))))
```

Then "xref-find-definitions" works with compressed files.